# SSML (Speech Synthesis Markup Language) editor

Tags: text-editor, xml, speech-synthesis, templating

Starting to play with SSML ([Speech Synthesis Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Synthesis_Markup_Language)), in relation to using it with the Amazon Polly text to speech process.

Looking for an SSML text editor that will validate syntax, plus help 'build' SSML elements (you start typing in an SSML element, and it shows you the parameters/options/etc for that element).

Lots of language editors, but haven't found an SSML editor yet.

Any ideas for an SSML editor, or a developer environment to use?

Comment: BTW. if you come up with a better answer than the one I posted, PLEASE post it. I'm stuggling with this myself in linux. My Wine is too drunk to run Loquendo. VMs are awkward. I"m trying to teach Geany tricks.

Comment: The googles came up with this link (in addition to my question) http://www.christopherstevens.cc/blog/2011/03/07/tts-tinymce/ . I have not tried it yet, but it is from 2011, so not sure how relevant. Can't find any other useful info.

Answer (score 0):

In a Win environment, Loquendo Director was pretty darned good. I'm not sure what Nuance has done with it since they bought Loquendo. I took a quick look at their website and didn't see it. Even if they have quit supporting and advertising it, that doesn't mean they won't sell you a copy, and it should still work. But I haven't used Widows in years now, so I'm guessing.

There doesn't appear to be anything like it in the 'nix world, but if you'd be satisfied with a utility to piggy back on your prefered text editor so you could highlight a string, and then pick tags (or whatever they call those `<blah,blah>foo</blah>` kind of things to wrap the strings in, or simply insert code at the point of the cursor, relieving you of both the tedium of typing them and remembering the exact syntax, geany has built in utilities that could be used that way. I wouldn't be surprised if gedit does as well. But even for a very simple editor, it should be pretty easy to cobble something to do this together with bash,  xclip,  and 9menu. That last is a much under-appreciated program imo.